# Javascript onclick autotriggering

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this code:

```
var bt_empty = document.getElementById("bt_empty");
if(bt_empty)
  bt_empty.onclick = emptyCart();
```

But every time I open the page, the button trigger itself. How can I avoid that?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from `emptyCart()`:

```
bt_empty.onclick = emptyCart;
```

By including parenthesis, it's executing the function and then assigning the return value to the `onclick` event, instead of assigning the actual function itself.

---

The only reason to include the parenthesis would be if the function returns a function. For example:

```
function emptyCart(){
    return function(){
        console.log("clicked");
    };
}

bt_empty.onclick = emptyCart();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But what is the sense of assigning the return value to onclick event? (in structure I mean)

Comment: Unless the `emptyCart()` function returns a function (to be executed onclick), there is no sense in assigning the return value.